# How to encrypt deep link for email without exceeding URL character limit?

Tags: c#, encryption, encryption-symmetric

It is looks like the encrypted string that is generated is too long and exceeds the maximum URL character limit when I am trying to encrypt `DeepLinkModel` having more than 20 count of `DeepLinkDataDto`.

What changes can I make to the code to ensure that the encrypted string is within the URL character limit?

```
var deepLinkQueryString 
    = DeepLinkDataProtectionProvider
    .EncryptString(deepLinkModel.AsJson(), deepLinkModelEncryptionKey)
```

I am using below class to encrypt and decrypt the query string data.

```
public static class DeepLinkDataProtectionProvider
{
    private static readonly byte[] InitializationVector 
        = new byte[] 
        { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16 };

    /// <summary>
    /// Encrypt invoice deep link query string
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="text">string text</param>
    /// <param name="key">string key</param>
    /// <returns>Encrypted string</returns>
    public static string EncryptString(string text, string key)
    {
        byte[] array;

        // Create a new instance of the Aes
        // class.  This generates a new key and initialization
        using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
        {
            aes.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);

            // Create an encryptor to perform the stream transform.
            ICryptoTransform encryptor 
                = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, InitializationVector);

            // Create the streams used for encryption.
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cryptoStream 
                    = new(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new(cryptoStream))
                    {
                        //Write all data to the stream.
                        streamWriter.Write(text);
                    }

                    array = memoryStream.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
        // Return the encrypted bytes from the memory stream.
        return Convert.ToBase64String(array);

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Decrypt invoice deep link query string
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cipherText">string cipherText</param>
    /// <param name="key">string key</param>
    /// <returns>Decrypted string</returns>
    public static string DecryptString(string cipherText, string key)
    {
        byte[] buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText.Replace(" ", "+"));

        // Create an Aes object
        // with the specified key and IV.
        using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
        {
            aes.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);

            // Create a decryptor to perform the stream transform.
            ICryptoTransform decryptor 
                = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, InitializationVector);

            // Create the streams used for decryption.
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new(buffer))
            {
                using (CryptoStream cryptoStream 
                    = new(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    using (StreamReader streamReader = new(cryptoStream))
                    {
                        // Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream
                        // and place them in a string.
                        return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is class which I am using for encryption:

```
   public class DeepLinkModel
    {
       
        [JsonProperty("RequestId")]
        public string RequestId { get; set; }

        
        [JsonProperty("UserId")]
        public string UserId { get; set; }

        
        [JsonProperty("Code")]
        public int Code { get; set; }

        
        [JsonProperty("Data")]
        public IEnumerable<DeepLinkDataDto> Data { get; set; }
    }

   
    public class DeepLinkDataDto
    {
       
        [JsonProperty("BillNumber")]
        public string BillNumber { get; set; }

       
        [JsonProperty("InvoiceNumber")]
        public string InvoiceNumber { get; set; }

      
        [JsonProperty("BillId")]
        public int BillId { get; set; }
    }
```

Below is the error which I am getting in the browser when trying to open that deep link URL:

> The resource you are looking for has been removed,  had its name changed,
> or is temporarily unavailable.

Comment: In general, rather than encrypting the data to put in a link you'd generate a suitably long random sequence and retain a lookup table locally that maps the random sequence back to the real data.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Do you mean I should store the encrypted string in database and generate the key for that and then load from Db with that key to encrypt?

Comment: There is no URL character limit as such. When you get back an encrypted query string, how long is it? Have you checked if the encrypted string is Html or URL `Encoded` before you used it as query string param in some email body?

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran Url is something like `https://{domain-name}.com/deeplink?token=AflK2YLdl+ZFKRycVPRZ9dbkjUIc2uLsK9nDUObbW` and token length is total 2668 characters.

Comment: See for yourself that the token above is not url-safe, and so must be `urlencoded` by your code, before using it in URL. Other than that, some email systems or even browsers may choke URL more than certain length, though there is no hard limit as such. It is one of those challenges that we need to face and workaround. Think of making use of a url shortner module.